# Why does my program only show one output when I have two inputs?

Tags: c#

I have inserted two input data (e.g. February, March), however the result only shows the last input which is the data in **March**.

After testing out for the codes, I realised it only shows the last input data. How should I do to show all the input data instead?

Incorrect: only one output is shown:

[image: Incorrect: only one output is shown]

Correct: should show all the input data:
[image: Correct: should show all the input data]

```
int count = 0;

foreach (DataTable dt in ds.Tables)    
{

    var ws = wb.Worksheets.Add(dt.TableName);

    if (count == 0)
    {
        string[] columnNames = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(x => x.ColumnName).ToArray();
        string[] rowValue = new string[dt.Rows.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            rowValue = dt.Rows[i].ItemArray.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray();
        }

        DateTime dttryparse;
        for (int i = 0; i < columnNames.Count(); i++)
        {
            ws.Cell(1, i + 1).SetValue(columnNames[i]);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < rowValue.Count(); i++)      
        {
            if (rowValue[i].Contains("$"))
            {
                ws.Cell(2, i + 1).SetValue(rowValue[i]);
                ws.Cell(2, i + 1).Style.NumberFormat.Format = "$ #,##0.00";
                ws.Cell(2, i + 1).DataType = XLCellValues.Text;
            }
            else if (rowValue[i].Contains("%"))
            {
                ws.Cell(2, i + 1).SetValue(rowValue[i]);
                ws.Cell(2, i + 1).DataType = XLCellValues.Text;
                ws.Cell(2, i + 1).Style.NumberFormat.Format = "0.0%";
            }
            else if (DateTime.TryParse(rowValue[i], out dttryparse))
            {
                ws.Cell(2, i + 1).SetValue(DateTime.Parse(rowValue[i]));
                ws.Cell(2, i + 1).DataType = XLCellValues.DateTime;
            }

        }
        ws.Columns().AdjustToContents();
        count += 1;
    }
    else
    {
        var rowValue = dt.Rows[0].ItemArray.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray();
        double dbltryparse = 0;
        DateTime dttryparse;

        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            if (rowValue[i].Contains("$"))
            {
                ws.Cell(2, i + 1).SetValue(rowValue[i]);
                ws.Cell(2, i + 1).Style.NumberFormat.Format = "$ #,##0.00";
                ws.Cell(2, i + 1).DataType = XLCellValues.Text;
            }
            else if (rowValue[i].Contains("%"))
            {
                ws.Cell(2, i + 1).SetValue(double.Parse(rowValue[i]));
                ws.Cell(2, i + 1).DataType = XLCellValues.Text;
                ws.Cell(2, i + 1).Style.NumberFormat.Format = "0.0%";
            }
            else if (DateTime.TryParse(rowValue[i], out dttryparse))
            {
                ws.Cell(2, i + 1).SetValue(DateTime.Parse(rowValue[i]));
                ws.Cell(2, i + 1).DataType = XLCellValues.DateTime;
            }
        }
        ws.Columns().AdjustToContents();
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to use a nested loop

Answer (score 3):

This

```
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    rowValue = dt.Rows[i].ItemArray.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray();
}
```

walks through all the rows, extracting the values, and overwriting them with the next rows values, until it comes to the last row (sounds familiar??) when it exits the loop, leaving `rowValue` containing the value of the last row.

If you stepped through this with a debugger it would be pretty obvious what was going on.